# Work with AJAX response with DOM methods

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm retrieving an entire HTML document via AJAX - and that works fine. But I need to extract certain parts of that document and do things with them.

Using a framework (jquery, mootools, etc) is not an option.

The only solution I can think of is to grab the body of the HTML document with a regex (yes, I know, terrible) ie. `<body>(.*)</body>` put that into the current page's DOM in a hidden element, and work with it from there.

Is there an easier/better way?

### Update

I've done some testing, and inserting an entire HTML document into a created element behaves a bit differently across browsers I've tested. For example:

- FF3.5: keeps the contents of the HEAD and BODY tags
- IE7 / Safari4: Only includes what's between ...
- Opera 10.10: Keeps HEAD and everything inside it, Keeps contents of BODY

The behavior of IE7 and Safari are ideal, but different browsers are doing this differently. Since I'm loading a predetermined HTML document I think I'm going to use the regEx to grab what I want and insert it into a DOM element - unless someone has other suggestions.

Comment: Just curious, but why are javascript frameworks not an option?

Comment: The jQuery implementation of what you want to do doesn't even bother to strip out the head, but it does strip out script tags, a comment suggesting it's to avoid some problems in IE.

Comment: @Tejs: because sometimes knowing how to do something yourself is of far greater value then "oh, XYZ framework does it for you".

Comment: I use jQuery all the time. I *could* work without it, and write the loops myself, but just to save myself the time later I would probably end up just duplicating jQuery's functionality anyway. It depends on what kind of project you're working on. If you're brushing up your raw Javascript skills, go right ahead, but if your goal is to push out a solid project as quickly as possible, you might benefit from taking advantage of what those who came before you have produced.

Comment: I live & breath jQuery - its made me forget how to do things without it, which I find pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elements can exist without being in the page itself. Just dump the HTML into a dummy div.

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = "<ul><li>foo</li><li>bar</li></ul>";
wrapper.getElementsByTagName('li').length; // 2
```

---

Given your edits, we run into a sticky situation, since you want `getElementById`. The matter would probably be easy if you could just create a new virtual document via `document.implementation.createDocument`, but IE doesn't support that at all.

Using a regex is a messy business, since what if we see something like `<body><input value="</body>" /></body>`? You could probably just make your regex greedy so that it moves on to the last instance of `</body>`, but if you do end up running into troubles, a more thorough parsing may be necessary. Even if a full framework isn't an option, you might end up wanting to use something like [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), the core of libraries like jQuery, to look for the element you want. Or, if you're really feeling in a purist sort of mood, you could write the recursive search function yourself - but why take that hit if someone else has already taken it?

```
var response_el = document.createElement('html'), foo;
response_el.innerHTML = the_html_elements_content;
foo = Sizzle('#foo', response_el);
```

Comment: I've tried this; it behaves rather oddly because I'm inserting an entire HTML document ... `<html> ... </html>`

Comment: @Stomped - if you *know* you'll be inserting a full HTML document, could you just create a `<html>` element, rip off the first 6 and last 7 characters, and set *that* as the `innerHTML`?

Comment: @Stomped - curious, I went to the jQuery source to look up how jQuery creates an element from `$('<html>whatever</html>')` to see if they had any shortcuts - turns out they just use a greedy regex to make sure it looks like `<tag>stuff</tag>`, and create a `<tag>` element and put `stuff` inside. You could use therefore either use their more generic approach, or just count on receiving a full HTML document and see above comment :)

Comment: Matchu: I just did the same thing (looked at jQuery source) - wish I had thought of doing so earlier. I also discovered that different browsers do things oddly when you insert an entire HTML doc (see my edit above)